# Python: how to pollute namespace with Enum values

Tags: python, enums

Curious if someone else has done this before.

I'd like to pollute my namespace with enum values.

For example in my code I'd like to refer to RED, GREEN and BLUE instead of Color.RED, Color.GREEN, and Color.BLUE.

The straightforward way would be to, after defining the enum, put `RED = Color.RED`, `GREEN = Color.Green` and `BLUE = Color.BLUE`... but I'd like to keep it DRY (Don't repeat yourself) meaning when I add a new Color to the Enum I don't want to have to explicitly add it to the namespace as well.

Would be nice if after defining `class Color(Enum):` you could `from Color import *`

I could write a `pollute_enum()` function which would monkey with `locals()` or something, but it'd be a problem to move that function into a utility package since `locals()` there would refer to something else.  I know there are modules that can walk up the call stack, but now that is getting really hacky.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why exactly would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure *why* you would want to do this, but you can update `locals` in your module on the fly.

**Note: Not recommended**

```
import enum

class Color(enum.Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

locals().update({color.name: color for color in Color})
```

Comment: `locals().update(Color.__members__)`? Also note that OP had already mentioned something like this. Plus this won't work for imports within a function.

Answer (score 1):

I am not one to advocate the use of global state, but you could create a module named `color_enums.py` and in it write:

```
RED = 0
BLUE = 1
GREEN = 2
```

And then in your code your could do:

```
from color_enums import *
if thing == GREEN:
    # do something
```

Comment: He wants the `RED` variable in his module to be `Color.RED`, not `0`.